# "Java platform SE binary has stopped working" for .setText() on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, settext

Yesterday I ran through my list of installed programs/features and removed a bunch that I thought I never used... guess I was wrong about at least one.

Now one of my Java applications crashes with "Java platform SE binary has stopped working." I've traced the issue, and it happens whenever I try to set the text in a JTextArea (.setText()). Any idea what I should look to fix or re-install that swing is apparently missing? Thanks!

(I'm using Java 1.8 update 45)

Comment: Best is to probably just remove and re-install the JRE / JDK.

Comment: setText(all those methods were changed) isn't thread safe from Java7

Comment: A complete uninstall / re-install did not fix the problem entirely. It works intermittently when I run it in Eclipse, and never works when I run the exported jar from command line.

Comment: Does the same code work on a different computer?

Comment: (Tip: use @<username> to reply to comments, otherwise there will be no notifications.)

Comment: @user1803551 yes. It works on other machines. One windows 7, the other windows 8. Running JRE 7/8 respectively.

Comment: Then it's some installation issue. This question should be migrated to SuperUser.